# Show statistical data (ex. population) of a country per state in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The main goal is for me to display a US map in google maps, highlighting all states. States should be plain colored, no markers, no city names, etc.. just plain colored, only showing the borders of each state. Then when clicking any state, a popup window will appear containing various info about the state ( ex. population, etc..) The pop up window is the same as the pop up window you see when clicking a marker.

I know some basic google maps api stuff, but I could use some help. Code samples would be awesome! Thanks.

Comment: Your question will probably get closed but the api doesn't (yet) provide country or states boundaries. You need an external data source. Have a look at fusion tables.

Comment: Yeah I am aware its not yet available, I am currently checking out google maps data layer. I'll post updates if I find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually need geo info? Google maps probably overcomplicates it if you don't. You might find it easier to use some simple javascript library that provides you with just the shapes.

Have a look at this for a start: [newsignature.github.io/us-map/](https://newsignature.github.io/us-map/)

`stateSpecificStyles` lets you customise the initial color of each state

Comment: Yes there are alternatives if you don't *need* google maps. You can also have a look at http://jvectormap.com/maps/countries/usa/

Comment: Nice recommendations, I'll surely take a look at these. However It would be preferable if its via google maps coz its not gonna be just in the US, I'll gonna need this same functionality to for some other countries, ex. UK, Australia, etc...

Also, for future version, I would need to go a little deeper such as per post code level. So I would prefer to have a google maps solution.